# JavaFX HTMLEditor: centered or right aligned texts lose their alignment when selecting(marking) them

Tags: javafx-2, java-7, java-8, fxml

Java version : Tried both JDK 7 and 8.
OS : Windows 7

I have implemented the JavaFX  HTMLEditor in to my app using FXML but now I have a problem with it. All text which have centered or right aligned, they lose their alignment and get back to left side when selecting(highlighting) the content of the HTMLEditor.

*. It is happening in the SceneBuilder preview window too.

I thought maybe it is a bug but I am not sure so asking here.
Also please let me know if there is a alternative exist to the javaFXHTMLEditor. So I can use it :).
Thank you.

[image: Before Selection]
[image: After Selection]

Answer (score 0):

I have that problem too. I think that is JavaFX bug. The same problem is when you type something in different font size in different rows. After select/highlight text by mouse from bottom right to top left fonts are changing to size from first selected row.
I've tested it on JDK7 32/64 and JDK8 32/64. No difference.